# Why StringBuilder when there is String?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I just encountered `StringBuilder` for the first time and was surprised since Java already has a very powerful `String` class that allows appending.

Why a second `String` class?

Where can I learn more about `StringBuilder`?

Comment: See also: [*Exact difference between CharSequence and String in java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11323962/642706) and [my nifty class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFk9.png).

Comment: I just wanted to note this actually came up as an interview question for me once. They asked what I would to populate a large String.....

Comment: The `StringBuilder` is 100s of times faster than strings when appending. Here's an article with a Java script you can run to see it for yourself: https://blog.terresquall.com/2023/08/try-it-yourself-compare-performance-java-string-stringbuilder-stringbuffer/

Answer (score 187, accepted):

`String` does not allow appending. Each method you invoke on a `String` creates a new object and returns it. This is because `String` is immutable - it cannot change its internal state.

On the other hand `StringBuilder` is mutable. When you call `append(..)` it alters the internal char array, rather than creating a new string object.

Thus it is more efficient to have:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i ++) {
    sb.append(i);
}
```

rather than `str += i`, which would create 500 new string objects.

Note that in the example I use a loop. As helios notes in the comments, the compiler automatically translates expressions like `String d = a + b + c` to something like

```
String d = new StringBuilder(a).append(b).append(c).toString();
```

Note also that there is `StringBuffer` in addition to `StringBuilder`. The difference is that the former has synchronized methods. If you use it as a local variable, use `StringBuilder`. If it happens that it's possible for it to be accessed by multiple threads, use `StringBuffer` (that's rarer)

Comment: +1. You could add: "hence StrungBuilder looks for performance" and "Java compilers substitutes expressions like A + B + C with new StringBuilder(A).append(B).append(C).toString() in order to avoid object creation performance penalties" :)

Comment: and all Thank you very much. You all deserve +1's (which will be delivered promptly :)

Comment: super like the recall of 'immutable' objects.

Comment: Great responses. What I miss however is the reason why we can't just have the compiler figuring out when to just use Stringbuilder *most of the time*, including in for loops, so that you don't need to think about it as a dev. :)

Comment: Good answer . I would like to add these lines :                                 String is immutable as the array (i.e char [] value) which holds string is declared final but in case of StringBuilder the array (i.e char [] value) which holds string  is not final. You can make changes in the array which holds string in case of Stringbuilder

Comment: are these methods `toLowerCase`, `toUpperCase` also create a new String?

Comment: @AdiyatMubarak yes.  An immutable object's state cannot be changed, so for example `toLowerCase` cannot change the current string it is being called from.   So it creates a new one from the current string.

Comment: Great answer! Why are other answers saying there is a performance cost of using String if the compiler will replace it anyways?

Answer (score 70):

Here is a concrete example on why -

```
int total = 50000;
String s = ""; 
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) { s += String.valueOf(i); } 
// 4828ms

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) { sb.append(String.valueOf(i)); } 
// 4ms
```

As you can see the difference in performance is significant.

Comment: Ps. I ran this on my Macbook Pro Dual core.

Comment: This does explain **Why StringBuilder when there is String?** This doesn't explain **Why StringBuilder is so fast.** but that is not The Question. So this is a valid answer.

Comment: @krmby - Agreed. To answer why is really meant for another question.

Comment: I think to make the comparison fair, you should include the time to perform a `s = sb.ToString();` at the end so at least you've done the same in both examples (result is a `string`).

Answer (score 19):

String class is immutable whereas StringBuilder is mutable.

```
String s = "Hello";
s = s + "World";
```

Above code will create two object because String is immutable

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");
sb.append("World");
```

Above code will create only one object because StringBuilder is not immutable.

Lesson: Whenever there is a need to manipulate/update/append String many times go for StringBuilder as its efficient as compared to String.

Answer (score 8):

StringBuilder is for, well, building strings. Specifically, building them in a very performant way. The String class is good for a lot of things, but it actually has really terrible performance when assembling a new string out of smaller string parts because each new string is a totally new, reallocated string. (It's **[immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)**) StringBuilder keeps the same sequence in-place and modifies it (**mutable**).

Answer (score 5):

The StringBuilder class is mutable and unlike String, it allows you to modify the contents of the string without needing to create more String objects, which can be a performance gain when you are heavily modifying a string. There is also a counterpart for StringBuilder called StringBuffer which is also synchronized so it is ideal for multithreaded environments.

The biggest problem with String is that any operation you do with it, will always return a new object, say:

```
String s1 = "something";
String s2 = "else";
String s3 = s1 + s2; // this is creating a new object.
```

Answer (score 5):

To be precise, StringBuilder adding all strings is O(N) while adding String's is O(N^2). Checking the source code, this is internally achieved by keeping a mutable array of chars. StringBuilder uses the array length duplication technique to achieve *ammortized* O(N^2) performance, at the cost of potentially doubling the required memory. You can call trimToSize at the end to solve this, but usually StringBuilder objects are only used temporarily. You can further improve performance by providing a good starting guess at the final string size.

Answer (score 3):

Efficiency.

Each time you concatenate strings, a new string will be created. For example:

```
String out = "a" + "b" + "c";
```

This creates a new, temporary string, copies "a" and "b" into it to result in "ab". Then it creates another new, temporary string, copies "ab" and "c" into it, to result in "abc". This result is then assigned to `out`.

The result is a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) of O(n²) (quadratic) time complexity.

`StringBuilder`, on the other hand, lets you append strings in-place, resizing the output string as necessary.

Comment: Many JVM implementations will compile your example into a StringBuilder and then convert the end result to String.  In such a case, it won't be assembled by repeated String allocations.

Answer (score 3):

StringBuilder is good when you are dealing with larger strings. It helps you to improve performance.

Here is a [article](http://kaioa.com/node/59) that I found that was helpful .

A quick google search could have helped you. Now you hired 7 different people to do a google search for you . :)

Comment: Aren't we all doing unpaid jobs here?

Comment: The article link mentioned is down/broken.

Answer (score 1):

Java has String, StringBuffer and StringBuilder:

- String : Its immutable
- StringBuffer : Its Mutable and ThreadSafe
- StringBuilder : Its Mutable but Not ThreadSafe, introduced in Java
  1.5

String eg:

```
public class T1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String s = "Hello";

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {

            s = s+"a";
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

}

output:  10 Different Strings will be created instead of just 1 String.

```
Helloa
Helloaa
Helloaaa
Helloaaaa
Helloaaaaa
Helloaaaaaa
Helloaaaaaaa
Helloaaaaaaaa 
Helloaaaaaaaaa 
Helloaaaaaaaaaa
```

StringBuilder eg :  Only 1 StringBuilder object will be created.

```
public class T1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("Hello");

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {    
            s.append("a");
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```