# how to push back a character in string in java

Tags: java, string

```
String str1 = "hello world";
String str2;
for (int i=0; i<str1.length(); i++)
{
    str2 = str2 + str1[i];
}
```

how do I push back elements of str1 in str2 sequencially?

Comment: What's not working with this approach?

Comment: It's really unclear what you want str2 to be after this loop has completed.

Comment: a `String` is not a stack.

Comment: `str1[i]` will not work, since it is not an array

Comment: Please consider using a `StringBuilder` for repeated concatenation due to the immutability of `String` objects, but also consider revising your solution to your problem; I'm unsure of the context of what you're trying to do but perhaps some sort of `Stack` implementation would suit your scenario better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why StringBuilder when there is String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234147/why-stringbuilder-when-there-is-string)

Comment: Why would you not just use `str1 + str2`, which has the same effect as the whole for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to initialize `String str2 = "";` . After that, do this inside the loop:

```
str2 = str2 + str1.charAt(i);
```

Or equivalently:

```
str2 += str1.charAt(i);
```

Either way, the trick is using the `charAt()` method for accessing a character at a given position.

Comment: And what if I want to check a character that whether it is alphabet or not?

Comment: That's a separate question, but OK. Use the methods in the `Character` class, in particular `Character.isAlphabetic()`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `str1[i]` use `str1.charAt(i)`.

```
for (int i=0; i<str1.length(); i++)
{
str2 = str2 + str1.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable.... cannot be changed after adding them.... you cannot change them, but you can create new ones with the result you want.

Typically, you should use StringBuilder to do the manipulation, and the toString() at the end to get a final String result.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1 = "hello world";
String str2 = "";
for (int i=0; i<str1.length(); i++)
{
    str2 = str2 + str1.charAt(i);
}
```

If you need to push the contents as a `Stack`, i.e. reverse the String.

```
String str1 = "hello world";
String str2 = "";
for (int i=str1.length()-1; i>-1; i--)
{
    str2 = str2 + str1.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the answers to the following questions.

- [Why StringBuilder when there is String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234147/why-stringbuilder-when-there-is-string)
- [String, StringBuffer, and StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971315/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder)
- [when to use StringBuilder in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java)