# initialize string dynamically in java

Tags: java, string

I want to initialize a string as follows:

```
public int function (  int count )  { 
String s_new = "88888...  'count' number of 8's "    <-- How to do this
//Other code 
}
```

Currently I'm not sure how to do this, so I've declared an int array ( int[] s_new ) instead and Im using for loops to initialize this int array.

EDIT: I meant that I need to initialize a string containing only 8's ... the number of times the digit 8 occurs is 'count' times.

Comment: Is the `88888...` part of the string supposed to represent the value of `count`? ie the user passes in 5, you put 5 eights there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases, it [is recommended to use a  `StringBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234147/why-stringbuilder-when-there-is-string):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s = "";
int count = 8;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sb.append('8');
}

s = sb.toString();

System.out.println(s);
```

**Output:**

```
88888888
```

Comment: This is a more efficient way to accomplish this than mine (memory/time).  +1

Comment: Java has a pretty smart compiler, all string `+` operations are actually converted to `StringBuilder.append's` so I doubt it, but when dealing with 8 characters output you need to be sure to optimize everything

Comment: @Philipp I was unaware of how the Java compiler handled such.  But, yeah.  Those 8 character outputs could take a mighty long time. ;)

Comment: @Philipp `+`  is internally implemented via `StringBuilder` but the compiler will do that in a loop here. `new StringBuilder(s).append('8').toString()` each time. You have move the builder out of the loop manually

Comment: @Philipp not in loops I believe and this isn't part of the Java spec so cannot be relied upon in non-Oracle compilers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Guava's `Strings.repeat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method:

```
String str = Strings.repeat("8", count);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
String s_new = "";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    s_new += "8";
}
return s_new;
```

Now, this is a naive solution.  A better solution (as is posted in other answers here) will use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` to accomplish this in a more efficient manner.

Also, further reading on the difference between those two options: [Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/355089/758446)

Comment: It compiles fine but is creating a new string object each iteration

Comment: @zapl Clarified that this is a naive solution, and not optimal.

Answer (score 2):

You can build strings using the `StringBuilder` class.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    sb.append('8')
String s_new = sb.toString();
```

`s_new` would then have as much `8` as you have `count`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution on pure Java using arrays:

```
public String repeat(char ch, int count) {
    char[] chars = new char[count];
    Arrays.fill(chars, ch);
    return new String(chars);
}
```