# Write JSON response to a text view

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

I am authenticating an external system via a REST API. The http authentication request is of the [Basic Authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) form. The response is in JSON format.

I am running this code under an `AsyncTask`.

- `url` The GET url of the API.
- `credentials` is the authentication credentials. It is a string.
- `response` is the text view.
- `getmessage` is a string variable.

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" +  Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT ));

// I am reading the response here,
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
buf = new BufferedReader(in);
getmessage = buf.readLine();

// After making the request, I am updating the response to a text view on the UI thread
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        response.setText(getmessage);
    }
});
```

I am unable to write the whole JSON data to the text view. I know that `buf.readline` returns the response till the end of a line. Right now I am only getting a part of the JSON response, "Not Authenticated:", but I need the whole response.

How do I update the whole JSON response to the text view (`response`)? If I loop the data using `buf.readline` in a loop then where can I use it? In which thread?

If there is anything unusual in my code. Please let me know.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: I don't know why was this question downvoted even after clearly specifying all the details.

Comment: i have made an ans, i hope you understand it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go trough [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class GetDataFromUrl extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" +  Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT ));

        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        buf = new BufferedReader(in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((getmessage = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(getmessage);
        }

        getmessage = sb.toString();

        return getmessage;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

         // Result will be available here (this runs on main thread)
         // Show result in text view here.
         response.setText(result);

    }
}
```

To understand better, as you call `AsyncTask`, `doInBackground` runs on the new thread created. Where the network call in placed and data is parsed. Now, we need to access the data on the main thread to update the `TextView` so override `onPostExecute` inside `AsyncTask` that is taking `result` as a parameter, from `doInBackground`. Also if you notice..

```
private class GetDataFromUrl extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String>
```

Here `URL` is the type we are passing to our `AsyncTask` for `doInBackground`

`String` is what we passing from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute`

and `Integer` is used to show progress for another method you can override i.e `onProgressUpdate` .. You can read more in the documentation liked above. Hope it was helpful.

Comment: I am getting the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Void` in this line `private class GetDataFromUrl extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String>`

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute(String result)` make sure you using `String result` and not `void result` int the `onPostExecute`

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

          // Result will be available here (this runs on main thread)
          // Show result in text view here.
          // Something like response.setText(result);
   response.setText(result);
   

     }` is what i have used

Comment: okay `protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) ` and make sure this is also `String` and not `void`. this should solve the mismatch of parameters

Comment: There was a prob with my code, I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You're only reading the first line of the response with readLine().  Call that in a loop until all lines are read, and append each new line to the previous.

Comment: That is ok. but how can I update that in the network thread ?

Comment: You're using an AsyncTask?  Do it in onPostExecute

Comment: Yes, I have told every little detail in my question .`I am running this code under the AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((getmessage = buf.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(getmessage);
}
getmessage = sb.toString();
```

**EDITED**

In your code:

```
getmessage = buf.readLine();
```

in variable getmessage reads only first line of JSON. You need to read all lines and concatenate it. How to know did you read all lines or not?

Here is what [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) says about it:

> *public String readLine()
>                   throws IOException*
>
> **Returns:**
>
> **A String** containing the contents of the line, not including any
>   line-termination characters, **or null** if the end of the stream has been
>   reached

As you can see, you should invoke this method, save result of it into variable, and check, if variable is **not null**, then you have read line of JSON. If variable is **null**, then you have read all JSON into variable and you have completely JSON String.

**StringBuilder** used to avoid creating unnecessary objects, read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234160/1796309)

Comment: Where do I put this piece of code ? If I put it in Aysnc it gives me an exception ?

Comment: Won't I get an exception ? How will you update the UI on the network thread ?

Comment: @Codester, I'm so sorry, I forget to copy this line: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); Please add it to top of my code

Comment: @gunr2171, thank you for your remark, I have edit my post and described solution

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correcly, you are trying to read all response data line by line. Can you try the following?

```
@Override
protected String doInBackGround(...){
    . . .
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 8 * 1024);
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    String response = sb.toString();
    return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String response){
    Textview tv = your_textview;
    your_textview.settext(whatever_part_you_get_from_response);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. Which thread do I need to put this piece of code ? If I put it under the `AsynchTask` I will get a network exception

Comment: @Codester you need to put this piece of code where you get the response, it should be in doInBackground

Comment: Yes, but using in doInBackground will throw an exception if we try to update the UI via a background thread.

Comment: @Codester that piece of code does not update any UI element. You need to return that response from DoInBackground and in onPostExecute you can get that result and set your TextView's text. Edited the answer.