# Java console program to print a summary of user input

Tags: java, string, terminal, bufferedreader

I want to sum up this information that the user typed in. How can I implement it without too much change?

**Console output**

```
Vorname(First Name) : Max
Name(Last Name) : Mustermann
Adresse(adress): Musterstraße 1.
Telefon(Phone Number): 030/12345678
```

**Code**

```
import java.io.*;
public class InformationsEingabeBD {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        String str;
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Vorname : ");
        str = input.readLine();

        System.out.print("Name : ");
        str = input.readLine();

        System.out.print("Adresse: ");
        str = input.readLine();

        System.out.print("Telefonnummer: ");
        str=input.readLine();

        Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this looks like a basic assignment, I assume you're not allowed utility classes like `StringBuilder`. So just assign each input to a variable and output these accordingly.

```
String firstName = input.readLine();
String lastName = input.readLine();
String address = input.readLine();
String telNr = Input.readLine(); //cast if necessary

Now output the values:

System.out.println("Vorname: "+firstName);
System.out.println("Nachname: "+lastName);
System.out.println("Adresse: "+address);
System.out.println("Telefon: "+telNr);
```

Or if you need to create one whole string append each input to the resulting string. E.g.

```
String res = "Vorname: "+input.readLine();
res += " Nachname: "+input.readLine();
//and so on
```

Note that usually you should avoid concatenation directly on a string object, since a new string object is created each time. Use `StringBuilder` for example. (See [Why StringBuilder when there is String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234147/why-stringbuilder-when-there-is-string) for more information).

Comment: @burakburi You're welcome. Please accept my answer :)