# Store different kind of types from a txt file to an array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a txt file like this

> 163 Money Drop 24
>
> 454 Happy 112
>
> 45 Nothing Without You 56

The first number is the id of the song which I want to store it as an integer, the second is a String !That is not one word! and the third is an integer which is the number of likes of the song. I want to store them in an array but when I use the scanner method I store them word by word and when a song has a name > 1 word I have a problem. Here's my testing code

```
public void readFile() {
    while(x.hasNext()){
        Song test = new Song(Integer.parseInt(x.next()), x.next(), Integer.parseInt(x.next()));
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can read the txt file, store the first number as an int and then scan for the whole string(name of the song) until the next element is a number?

Comment: What happens when the number is part of the song name?

Comment: There's not such a thing in my case

Comment: You could read the while line and then parse it using a regex, but if you can still change the format of the text file, it would be better to have a dedicated separator character like ','  or ';' between your fields (i.e. turn your textfile in a *.csv, this also makes it easy to open it in a spreadsheet program like excel).

Comment: Why don't you simply read the line in `str`, parse as int the `substring(0, firstIndexOf whitespace)`,  parse as int the `substring(lastIndexOf whitespace)`, and then use substr(firstIndexOf, lastIndexOf)` as a title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way without regex is probably to use the scanner to read in the single words of your title and then combine them to create the name. Something like this:

```
int id = myScanner.nextInt();
String title = myScanner.next();

//while title has more words
while(!myScanner.hasNextInt()){
   //append words with whitespace
   title = title + " " + myScanner.next();
}

int likes = myScanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: I like the idea. One suggestion, instead of concatenation it is better to use StringBuilder to get better performance. More info: [Why StringBuilder when there is String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5234147)

Comment: It's wrong because maybe the title has int value for example 444 50 cent 323

Comment: @Spara According to first two comments: "(1) What happens when the number is part of the song name? -> (2 - OP) There's not such a thing in my case".

Comment: You can extend the code so that it appends even the numbers in case that there is another number after the number we just read

Comment: @Pshemo but in general it's better to consider all situations and the code should not get exception on invalid inputs

Comment: while(!myScanner.hasInt()) Intellij IDEA says cannot find method hasInt

Comment: @user3699548 You are looking for `hasNextInt()` in this case.

Comment: Tried that and didn't work it stops when a song has a title > 1 word

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no separator character, I assume that the first word is the id and the last word is number of likes and the others on mid is the name. So you can use this method:

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] slices = line.split(" ");
        Song test = new Song(Integer.parseInt(slices[0]), line.substring(slices[0].length() + 1, line.lastIndexOf(" ")), slices[slices.length - 1]);
```