# Is this the most efficient way to append a character array to a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I want to read an input stream with a buffer and append each buffer to a string until the stream is empty.

```
char[] buffer = new char[32];

while ((bytesRead = streamReader.read(buffer, 0, 32)) != -1)
   message += new String(buffer);
```

I couldn't find a method of `String` to append a character array directly and opted for this. Is there a way to know if this is wasting cycles copying the character array to a new string, only to immediately discard it?

This may be premature optimization but it glares at me pretty strongly.

I believe this constructor calls `Arrays.copyOf()`.

Comment: Use StringBuilder and its append methods instead of `message += new String(buffer);`

Comment: Possibly related: [Why StringBuilder when there is String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5234147)

Comment: The copying to a String does an extra copy, but is nowhere near as expensive as accumulating into a String instead of a StringBuilder.  Also, StringBuilder can append a `char[]` directly, so that's two reasons you should be using StringBuilder.

Comment: You will find over a large file that this is about the worst way to do it, not the best.

Answer (score 1):

No.

There are more efficient ways. Using a `java.util.StringBuilder` in your loop is more efficient as it is performing a series of operations. In your loop, += will create another String object each time. For example, if you were to do `String d = a + b + c + d...` for 1_000_000 Strings, then you'd be making 1_000_000 String objects as waste. Strings are immutable.

Related Link:

[String concatenation: concat() vs "+" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)

Off-Site Link but still related
https://dzone.com/articles/string-concatenation-performacne-improvement-in-ja