# String vs String builder. which is faster? If stringbuilder then why use string

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

i am confused between string and string builder which is faster, i know string builder is faster than string in concatenation operations. But what if i don't want to use concatenation operations. If stringbuilder is faster why we mostly use string.

Comment: For concat 2 strings, once, there is no real need of use StringBuilder, which is more when you need complex chaining or loop chaining

Comment: `StringBuilder` is faster at **building strings**, i.e. concatenating strings. If you don't need concatenation, then use a `String`, since a `StringBuilder` would be overkill, and slower.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Comment: Another possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5234147/1288408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of `String` is that it is *immutable*: once constructed, the contents of a string instance cannot change anymore. This means that you pass strings by reference without making copies all the time.

For example, suppose you would pass a `StringBuilder` to a class. Then you could change the contents of that `StringBuilder` afterwards, and confuse the class. So the class would need to make a copy to make sure that the content doesn't change without it knowing about it. With a `String` this is not necessary, because a `String` is immutable.

Now, when you're in the process of building a string, this immutability is actually a problem, because a new `String` instance must be created for every concatenation. That's why the `StringBuilder` class exists: it is an auxiliary class which is intended to build strings (hence the name).

In practice, it's often not necessary to use a `StringBuilder` explicitly. The Java compiler will automatically use a `StringBuilder` for you when you write things like `String result = "some constant" + a + b;`. Only with complex building logic (using `if` and `for` blocks, for example) you need to do that yourself.