# Make printf write faster to the Windows commandline

Tags: c++

I'm analyzing some high resolution midi data. I'm writing it to the stdout but since there is so much data coming in it takes seconds for them all to display after I did the actual action.

Currently this line writes to the commandline:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> message;
...
printf("W 1 = %03d, W 2 = %03d, W 3 = %03d \n",(int)message[2],(int)message2[1],(int)message2[2]);
```

Comment: How fast can you read? By which I mean, do you really need to display everything that you are displaying to the command window rather than just the "important" stuff?

Comment: why not write to a file? Then analyse the file at your heart's content? I would second Charles, push only the critical stuff the console...

Comment: For the record, writing to stdout *is* writing to a file. The program doesn't know whether it ends up on the console or whether it's redirected to a file or piped to some other process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a good chance that this is a video driver issue - video card manufacturers probably don't always pay a lot of attention to console window performance.  I've had rigs with painfully slow - I mean tooth-extraction painful - console windows that had probably 100 times improvement in that area by updating the video driver.

Comment: Wow, that was a genius idea.
I'm running a bitcoin-miner which uses 100% of the GPU-performance. After altering its agression it works fine now.

Comment: wow dint know that.. something that goes to my knowledge bank.. thanks @michael

Answer (score 0):

why dnt you use a string builder class like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462951/c-equivalent-of-stringbuffer-stringbuilder) and append all your output string and write to the output at the end?

What do you think?

Comment: If data is created faster then it is printed I definitely would save it using one thread and print it somewhere using a second thread...

Comment: @zzzz, oops, I didn't follow the link! :( I saw the title (and forgot that SO strips the ++, so it looked like a c-equivalent...) doh!