# need to build string in C++ without a predefined buffer size

Tags: c++, arrays

All the examples I have sees on the web for creating a string with sprintf use a statically declared array whose size is fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   char str[80];

   sprintf(str, "Value of Pi = %f", M_PI);
   puts(str);

   return(0);
}
```

I want to be able to do this with a dynamically sized array in the simplest way possible.
I have to write some code that will print the values that compose the array:

```
    printf("id=%s %s-array is: ", id.value(), name);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < depths.size(); i++) {
        printf("%f,", depths[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

But I don't want to do this with separate printfs.. I want to be able to put it all in a buffer that fits the string I am writing at runtime. I am inclined to think that sprintf is the best way to do this, but if there are other functions I can use in C++. Let me know.

Comment: C or C++?  Please choose.

Comment: I choose the C++ language (coudn't just write C++, too few chars :S)

Comment: (if on Win32) Consider using [`_scprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32cf9tb(v=vs.90).aspx), which will tell you how big a buffer you need.  Then allocate your buffer, then call `sprintf`

Comment: If you're using C++, why not use `std::string`? You don't have to specify a length with that.

Comment: What's wrong with building your formatted string in the idiomatic c++ way using a `std::stringstream `

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462951/c-equivalent-of-stringbuffer-stringbuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go the more idiomatic way and use a `std::ostringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{    
    std::ostringstream os;    
    os << "id=" << id.value() << " " << name << "-array is: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < depths.size(); i++) {
        os << std::fixed << depths[i] << ",";
    }    
    os << "\n";

    std::cout << os.str();
}
```

No need to worry out buffer size or memory allocation then ..

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic C++ way (as @Troy points out) is using a string stream:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::ostringstream ss;
   ss << "Value of Pi = " << M_PI;

   std::string str = ss.str();

   std::cout << str << '\n';

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use std::endl?

Comment: @SoapBox Is there a reason to flush immediately? Always remember that `std::endl` does "print newline and flush."

Comment: Do you always answer questions with questions? :-P  I've always been told to prefer std::endl to \n just for "C++iness" since it almost never matters whether you flush right away or not.  (When it does matter, obviously then you'd chose the one that provides the semantics you need.)

Comment: @SoapBox No, why? Just kidding, sorry. I just meant "I don't think there's a reason for the flush."

Comment: I don't understand, it isn't working on my test app. I'm using visual studio 2010, building a win32 console app

Comment: Error 1 error C2079: 'ss' uses undefined class 'std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' c:\users\egutarra\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testapp1\testapp1\testapp1.cpp 12 1 TestApp1

Comment: @Flethuseo Sorry, I missed one header; added it in the meantime.

Comment: It's not recognizing M_PI.. Error 1 error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identifier c:\users\egutarra\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testapp1\testapp1\testapp1.cpp 14 1 TestApp1

Comment: @Flethuseo Add a define `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` before including `<cmath>`. It's a Microsoft-specific thing. And I'd suggest you accept Troy's answer instead of mine - I only added mine (as wiki) because I thought he'd leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use snprintf with a string length of zero to determine how many characters would have been printed.  Then, allocate a buffer of this length, and re-traverse the list with the allocated buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a C++ string using a `printf`-like call with a utility function such as:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string build_string(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    size_t len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    std::vector<char> vec(len + 1);
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(vec.data(), len + 1, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return std::string(vec.begin(), vec.end() - 1);
}
```

`std::string msg = build_string("Value of Pi = %f", M_PI)` will work as expected, and you can use `c_str()` to pass the corresponding `char *` to functions that expect it (so long as you are careful that the `string` object is not destroyed before they are done).

Comment: I'm getting this warning: 1>c:\users\egutarra\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testapp1\testapp1\testapp1.cpp(12): warning C4996: 'vsnprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using vsnprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: it's suggesting me to use vsprintf_s.. is it better to use that one?

Comment: @Flethuseo `vsnprintf` is no less safe than `vsnprintf_s`, so you probably want to add that `#define`, at least for that function. Ultimately it's up to you - the function as written in the answer is portable C++, while `vsnprintf_s` is a Microsoft-specific extension.

Comment: I think this code will include the trailing NULL in the `std::string`. You could just use a correctly-sized `std::string` directly instead of the intermediate `std::vector` and `pop_back()` to strip the trailing NULL.

Comment: @Blastfurnace You're right about the trailing `\0`, thanks for the correction. I was wary of the further optimization of removing the `vector` since my memory seems to tell me that an `std::string` can be implemented as a non-contiguous buffer.

Comment: You're correct, I've been spoiled by the C++11 standard behavior.