# C++ best practice of concat strings

Tags: c++, c++11

in case of frequently concatenating strings to form final result, what's the best practice to do this? (in C++11 or later)

What about `string::append()` or `ostringstream`?

And another question: if I use many `+` to concatenating strings, will modern compiler optimize it in most efficient way? (Just like Java now can optimize string concat using StringBuilder)

Comment: Personally I would code it so it looks good. Then profile it and determine if the performance is okay for you.

Comment: See this question about c++ equivalent to Java's String Builder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462951/c-equivalent-of-stringbuffer-stringbuilder

Comment: I use `s1 += s2`,  am sure that would be identical to `s1.append(s2)`. I avoid `std::stringstream` is speed if required because its relatively slow.

Comment: Use `string::operator+=`. It's probably exactly identical to `string::append`. `stringstream` has a different purpose.

Comment: On the inside `std::string` probably works more like `StringBuilder` because `Java` `String` is read-only so they can't be appended to. `std::string`, on the other hand can.

Comment: @NathanOliver never said enough. Write clean code, then look for something else if you profiled your software and realized that code is really too slow for your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case that somehow you think of StringBuilder in mananged realms.

You can use Alphabet (Google) Library, ABCLib, ABCL or just Abseil.

[***Abseil's Strings library***](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/strings) look ahead and allocate all it need at once, then build string in it like you want. For concat job, you just need absl::StrCat() and absl::StrAppend().

I'm not any good at explaining things. Perhaps this [***godbolt***](https://godbolt.org/g/V45pXJ) link below may speak better than I do.

[godbolt.org/g/V45pXJ](https://godbolt.org/g/V45pXJ)

Learn more on YouTube : [***CppCon 2017: Titus Winters “Hands-On With Abseil”***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xu7q8dGvuwk&t=32m) (ffw to 32min)

[youtube.com/watch?v=xu7q8dGvuwk&t=32m](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xu7q8dGvuwk&t=32m)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <absl/strings/str_cat.h>

int main()
{
    std::string s1,s2,s3,s4,
                s5,s6,s7,s8,
                s9,s10,s11,s12;
    std::getline(std::cin, s1);
    std::getline(std::cin, s2);
    std::getline(std::cin, s3);
    std::getline(std::cin, s4);
    std::getline(std::cin, s5);
    std::getline(std::cin, s6);
    std::getline(std::cin, s7);
    std::getline(std::cin, s8);
    std::getline(std::cin, s9);
    std::getline(std::cin, s10);
    std::getline(std::cin, s11);
    std::getline(std::cin, s12);
    std::string s = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 +  // a call to operator+ for each +
                    s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 +
                    s9 + s10 + s11 + s12;

    // you shall see that
    // a lot of destructors get called at this point
    // because operator+ create temporaries

    std::string abseil_s = 
       absl::StrCat(s1,s2,s3,s4,  // load all handles into memory
                    s5,s6,s7,s8,  // then make only one call!
                    s9,s10,s11,s12);

    return s.size() + abseil_s.size();

    // you shall see that
    // only "real" s1 - s12 get destroyed
    // at these point
    // because there are no temporaries!

}
```

---

#### Update 2021

Today you can alternatively use `fmt:format` or `std::format` when the `c++20` [library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) implementation completed. (Current `fmtlib` now bumps support into c++14.)
The `format` will lookahead like in Abseil `StrCat`, so no wasted temporaries.

```
    string fmt_s = 
        fmt::format("{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}",
                    s1,s2,s3,s4,  // load all handles into memory
                    s5,s6,s7,s8,  // then make only one call!
                    s9,s10,s11,s12);
```

[[LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/o5MWasor7)]

Comment: The godbolt link is broken... or at least, it takes me to an empty godbolt.org page.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Indeed. Sorry, I didn't recheck that. Fixed already.

Comment: I opened this answer to mention `StrCat`. Thank you for writing it!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need any of the features of an `std::ostringstream`, plain append to the same string will generally be the most efficient way if your final objective is to obtain a single `std::string` (and calling `reserve` adequately beforehand can shave off some useless allocations). Internally an `std::ostringstream` works mostly the same way, but it adds some overhead for the extra layers.

> And another question: if I use many `+` to concatenating strings, will modern compiler optimize it in most efficient way? (Just like Java now can optimize string concat using StringBuilder)

`std::string` is already something like a `StringBuilder`, as it's a mutable type that grows efficiently, so you don't need to use a different type for this.

Now, in C++03 multiple concatenated `+` will create all the relevant temporary strings, so if you wanted to keep it efficient you'll have to explicitly use `+=` repeatedly over the target string.

OTOH, C++11 added overloads of `operator+` taking rvalue references, which allow the allocated storage for the temporary strings to be recycled/expanded for the next concatenation, so in most cases efficiency should be comparable - thanks @Daniel Schepler for pointing it out.

One case where I think this would fall short is something like:

```
big_string += a + b + c;
```

In this case, `a + b + c` itself is computed efficiently, but without considering the fact that it's going to be appended to another string (so, probably without any extra allocation). You'd be better off with either the "traditional" method, or with

```
big_string = std::move(big_string) + a + b + c;
```

Comment: If using C++11, `string::operator+` has several overloads involving rvalues which will be able to reuse the allocated storage from one temporary value to the next.

Comment: @DanielSchepler woa that's something that I managed to miss in 8+ years of C++11. Fixing the answer...

Comment: @DanielSchepler @MatteoItalia Is this safe? I guess this rvalue-based `operator+` returns an rvalue reference to the string itself, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/66952566/6222803 says `std::string` is not _MoveAssignable_

Comment: @TuffContender: `operator+` ([number 7](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B)) returns an actual object that is distinct from `big_string`, so there should be no self-assignment problem; the return value is also an rvalue, so it should always trigger the same overload in the subsequent `+` calls, and the move assignment operator ([number 2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)) at the end. Hence, there should be no problem nor any extra copy.